# Grails - Unique constraint not working as expected

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In the following service method the expected behavior is that an exception is thrown if we try to insert a field that is marked as unique a second time.

```
def lock(String task) {
    TaskLock lock = new TaskLock(taskName: task, lockTime: new Date())
    try {           
        lock.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Do something
    }           
}
```

The field taskName is unique. If we try to insert a TaskLock with a duplicate taskName no exception is thrown. But on the other hand, the original value in the database in not updated either (date remains from the original insert).

If we change to above code to the following:

```
def lock(String task) {
    TaskLock lock = new TaskLock(taskName: task, lockTime: new Date())
    try {
        TaskLock.getAll()
        lock.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Do something
    }           
}
```

Then everything works as expected. Could someone explain to me why this is the case (seems to be linked to the local Hibernate cache) and what is the correct way to get a unique constraint working in the above example? Using Grails 3.3.2. with the in-memory H2 db with a single data-source.

Edit: Added the TaskLock domain class:

```
class TaskLock {       
    String taskName
    Date lockTime

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id name: 'taskName', column: 'TASK_NAME', generator: 'assigned'
    }

    static constraints = {
        taskName(unique: true, nullable: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to see your domain class TaskLock in my chrystal ball but saw only mist. Could you assist a bit and show how did you set your constraints?

Comment: @AntonHlinisty added the domain class.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use custom validator instead of unique true because it more optimized.

Here is the example showing the custom validator with a good reason :-
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-unique-constraint-optimization-part-2/